# How to add multiple menus in Wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, while-loop

I am developing a new Wordpress theme, and I need two menus, the main menu, and the footer menu. This is what I have in functions.php:

```
if ( function_exists('register_nav_menus')) {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'main' => 'Main Menu',
            'footermenu' => 'Footer Menu'
        )
    );
}
```

And, I am calling two menus, one in header.php and other in footer.php:

```
<?php $main_menu = array('menu' => 'main', 'container' => 'nav' ); wp_nav_menu( $main_menu ); ?>

<?php $footer_menu = array('menu' => 'footermenu', 'container' => 'nav' ); wp_nav_menu( $footer_menu ); ?>
```

I am also assigning both menus a different menu in Wordpress Menus Manager, but in both menus, only the menu I assign to the first one is shown. I don't know why. Can anybody help me solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: From a glance, your code looks correct to me. Are you saying the main menu is being displayed for both the main_menu and footer?

Comment: Where are you calling "register_nav_menus"? I call mine in the `after_setup_theme` action hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've solved this. Instead of `menu`, I had to use `theme_location`, because this represents the menu chosen from the menu admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array to store menu name and using loop we can iterate through array and use `wp_nav_menu()` function to get menus.

```
<?php
            $menus = array('menu_about','menu_services','menu_facilities');
        ?>
        <nav  class="footer-navigation">
        <?php foreach ($menus as $value) { ?>
            <ul class="footer-navigation-wrapper">
                <?php
                     wp_nav_menu(array(
                    'menu'           => $value,
                    'items_wrap'     => '%3$s',
                    'container'      => false,                      
                    'link_before'    => '<div>',
                    'link_after'     => '</div>',
                    'fallback_cb'    => false,
                    ));
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
    </nav>
```